# String to ASCII code conversion and tie them

Tags: c, string, ascii

The code is c and compiling on gcc compiler.
How to append string and char like as following example

```
unsigned char MyString [] = {"LOREM IPSUM" + 0x28 + "DOLOR"};
```

Comment: Perhaps you should first tell us what language this is...

Comment: fyi: gcc is a compiler that can handle many languages. you should say "c" or "c++'.

Comment: C :) sorry forgot to say

Comment: 0x128 is a rather large `unsigned char` value.

Comment: @Saim you should use single-quotes around `char` literals and double-quotes around string-literals (i.e. `char`-arrays). So `char myStr[] = { 'L', 'O', 'R', 'E', 'M' .... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned char MyString [] = {"LOREM IPSUM\050DOLOR"};
```

The `\050` is an octal escape sequence, with 050 == 0x28. The language standard also provides *hex* escape sequences, but `"LOREM IPSUM\x28DOLOR"` would be interpreted as a *three*-digit hex (`\x28D`), the meaning of which (since it would be overflowing the usual 8-bit `char`) would be implementation-defined. Octal escapes *always* end after three digits, which makes them safer to use.

And while we're at it, there is no guarantee whatsoever that your escapes would be considered ASCII. There are machines using EBCDIC natively, you know, and compilers defaulting to UTF-8 -- which would get you into trouble as soon as you go beyond `0x7f`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @DevSolar, but when i use \014 octal is failed, using 0x0e working well.

Comment: @Saim: Errr.... note that the kind of escapes I am pointing at here are only working **within string literals**. You can use either `\014` or `\x0e` **within** a literal, or you can use `014` or `0x0e` **outside** them. So I am not at all sure what you've done to your code, just a very bad feeling about it...

Comment: unsigned char MyString [] = {"x variable=%x",x}; @DevSolar can i use like 

printf(stderr, "%s %s", myfoo, mybar);

 that?

Comment: @SaimGokkoyun: I seriously suggest you get a good book. Your first construct is initializing an array of type `unsigned char []` with one element of type `const char *` and one `x` of unclear type. Your second construct won't work, because you've confused `printf()` and `fprintf()`. Trying to learn by trial & error does not yield acceptable results.